# How can I remove "Azure AD Connect Sync" and my (stale) on-premises domain?

Tags: azure, entra-id

After having played around with Azure AD Connect in my testbed I decided to remove it and revert back to a 100% cloud environment.

I therefor uninstalled all the local Azure AD Connect components from my on-premises domain controller. Then I stopped synchronization by using the `MSonline` powershell module.

```
PS> Install-Module -Name MSonline
PS> Connect-MSolservice
PS> Set-MsoldDirSyncEnabled -EnableDirSync $false
```

After having issued the above commands the status switched to: `Not Installed` and the Last Sync status now shows `Sync has never run`. Also `(Get-MSOLCompanyInformation).DirectorySynchronizationEnabled` now returns `false`, so everything regarding the sync service should be turned off now.

[image]

However when clicking on `Seamless single sign-on` my local domain still shows up:

[image]

Why is that and how can I entirely remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by reinstalling Azure AD Connect and disabled SSO through the configuration wizard. Then I issued `Set-MsoldDirSyncEnabled -EnableDirSync $false` again to disable the AD Sync one more time. And everything is fine.